# Chrome extensions: chrome.storage.local.get headache

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-storage

Trying to build a simple Chrome extension to output the whole contents of localStorage.

How difficult should it be? Spent a few hours researching and trying, still doesn't work :(

Appreciate assistance!

For example:

```
function load() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
    var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
    alert(allKeys.count);
  });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  load();
});
```

outputs 'undefined'

Some other ways I tried actually contained an object, but I couldn't do anything with it (no count/length, no JSON.stringify, no toString() etc).

Manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "chrome://favicon/"
  ]
```

How can I output the whole localStorage within my extension popup?

Please help!

Comment: `chrome.storage.local` is not the same as `localStorage`. To view the extension's local storage you can use either `chrome.storage.local(null, a => console.log(a))` or, for localStorage, simply `console.log(localStorage)`

Comment: I meant `chrome.storage.local.get(null, a => console.log(a))`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I don't want the extension's local storage - I need the page's global storage (the domain that is open in Chrome at the moment when I initiate the extension).

Comment: Which page? If it is a webpage outside your extension, you have to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Answer (score 2):

Could you try `allKeys.length`?

`Object.keys(items)` would return you an array. Array by default doesn't have a property `count`. I think you mean `length`.

---

If you need the webpage's local storage (the domain loaded in your tab), instead of the extension page's local storage, I don't think you can do that.

**Iván Nokonoko** had a nice point that you need to inject the script in order to interact with the loaded web page, however the problem is the injected script is forced to run in an isolated environment, in which you only have access to the DOM tree, but no access to the original JS environment, thus the `localStorage` variable that you can get, is the one in your own isolated env, rather than the original one.

Quoted from [Chrome Content Scripts API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

And I believe injecting code has the same restrication as content script.

I think this restriction is for safety consideration. It's OK to expose the DOM tree to extensions, in the worst case the extension would mess up the view. But if expose the JS env, such as the local storage to extension, then it could be dangerous, as extension is capable of accessing/tampering data.

Comment: allKeys.length returns 0. I think my approach of extracing localStorage is incorrect.

Comment: I have seen Chrome extensions which do that - they display cookie/localStorage info of the currently open Chrome tab. So there should be a way.

Answer (score 2):

To show the localStorage of currently active tab, try:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:'JSON.stringify(localStorage)'},function(result) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(result[0]));
});
```

***Working*** example:

**popup.html**

```
<body>
    <div id=ls></div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:'JSON.stringify(localStorage)'}, res => {
    var ls = document.querySelector("#ls"), lsObj = JSON.parse(res[0]), lsHtml = "";
    for (var key in lsObj)
        lsHtml += "<p>" + key + " : " + lsObj[key] + "</p>";
    ls.innerHTML = lsHtml ? lsHtml : "The active tab has nothing in localStorage";
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the extension, sorry. Can someone provide a working example please, for a Chrome extension?

Comment: @Vahe   It DOES work in Chrome extension (it was tested in one). What localStorage are you trying to get? The extension's or a different webpage's?

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid - produces nothing in my popup.

If I try to execute chrome.tabs.executeScript separately in my console, I get 

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeScript' of undefined**

Comment: It produces nothing when the active tab has **nothing** in `localStorage`. Try with a webpage with something in `localStorage`. I've updated the code to make it even clearer