# Accessing WebStorage (locaStorage) of parent page from Chrome Extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, web-storage

How to access WebStorage (locaStorage) of parent page (current tab) from inside Chrome Extension popup?

Actually, chrome.storage.sync access the local storage of the popup.htm page not the parent page.
So, is this possible? Or, is it prevented for some security reasons?

Note: the following is about saving and accessing the local storage inside the popup page. What I need is the local storage of the **parent page** (current tab).

[saving and retrieving from chrome.storage.sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531102/saving-and-retrieving-from-chrome-storage-sync)

Comment: You need a content script. It can access `localStorage` of the web page.

Comment: You have a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48545088/3930351)